# How do I invoke testng annotated methods using reflection api in java and also obtain the testng report for that?

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I want to invoke testng annotated methods by using reflection api and obtain the test results in a  testng report(html file generated by testng). I am able to invoke the methods but the report is not being generated. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What framework are you using

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run test methods by yourself. Testng is doing it and produce the report.

You have many ways to interact with TestNG: listeners, reporter API,... 
Have a look at the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).